# form validation returns False

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm dealing with form validation. For some mysterious reason my `form.is_valid()` returns false. I looked over other related topics here on SO but none of them helped. I'm getting no errors from `form.errors`.

view:

```
def index(request):
    form = TestCaseForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            TestCase.objects.create(
                name=request.POST['name'],
                documentation=request.POST['documentation'],
                steps=request.POST['steps'],
                tags=request.POST['tags'],
                setup=request.POST['setup'],
                teardown=request.POST['teardown'],
                template=request.POST['template'],
                timeout=request.POST.get(int('timeout')),
            )
            return redirect('/list')
        else:
            for i in form.errors:
                print(i)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class TestCaseForm(forms.Form):
    name                    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Name'}), label='')
    documentation            = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                            'placeholder': 'Enter Documentation'}), label='')
    steps                    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Steps'}), label='')
    tags                     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Tags'}), label='')
    setup                    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Setup'}), label='')
    teardown                 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Teardown'}), label='')
    template                 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Template'}), label='')
    timeout                  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Timeout (optional)'}),
                                     required=False, label='')
```

models.py:

```
class TestCase(models.Model):
"""
The test case
"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    documentation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    steps = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    setup = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    teardown = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    template = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit"
style="margin-top:10px;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form = TestCaseForm()
if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
```

You have not bound the form to any data. Therefore `form.is_valid()` will always be `False` but `form.errors` will be empty.

Change your view to use the following structure:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Bound form for POST requests
    form = TestCaseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    # Unbound form for GET request
    form = TestCaseForm()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I spent so much time just on this. I'm quite new to Django forms.